# how do we compute the definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I would like an explanation regarding definite integrals. Here is this question

> Compute the definite integral
>
> $$\int_0^2\max\left(x, x^2\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$\int_0^2 \max (x, x^2)dx=\int_0^1 xdx+ \int_1^2 x^2dx
=\frac12+\frac73=\frac{17}6$$

Answer (score 3):

I assume it just means
$$\int_{0}^{1}x dx + \int_{1}^{2}x^{2} dx$$
since $x^{2}\geq x$ for $1\leq x\leq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

hint: max, min functions change the definition of the actual function at points of concern so try to simplify the problem by decomposing the domain or in simple words to find which function is bigger in which sub-domain and piece-wise integrate the sub-problems

suggestion: I try to visualize graphs of the function while solving these problems!